# Import multiple excel files into pandas and create a column based on name of file

Tags: python, pandas

I have multiple excel files in one folder which I want to read and concat together,but while concating together I want to add column based on name of the file

```
'D:\\156667_Report.xls',
'D:\\192059_Report.xls',
'D:\\254787_Report.xls',
'D:\\263421_Report.xls',
'D:\\273554_Report.xls',
'D:\\280163_Report.xls',
'D:\\307928_Report.xls'
```

I can read these files in pandas with following script

```
path =r'D:\' # use your path
allFiles = glob.glob(path + "/*.xls")
frame = pd.DataFrame()
list_ = []
for file_ in allFiles:
   df = pd.read_excel(file_,index_col=None, header=0)
   list_.append(df)

frame = pd.concat(list_)
```

I want to add column as `Code` in all the files which I read.Code will be numbers from filename e.g. `156667,192059`

Answer (score 1):

why not just match

```
foo = re.match('\.*_Report', file_)
num = foo[:6]`
df['Code']= num
```

Inside your loop?

Answer (score 0):

One you could do this, is by using `join`, `isdigit`, inside a `list comprehension`.

The `isdigit` will get only the numbers from the file name (in a list), and the `join` function will join them back into 1.

To be clear, you could change your `for` loop to this:

```
for file_ in allFiles:
   df = pd.read_excel(file_,index_col=None, header=0)
   df['Code'] = ''.join(str(i) for i in file_ if i.isdigit())
   list_.append(df)
```

which will add a column called `Code` in each df.